# How to run unit tests in TFS (using vNext)

Tags: jasmine, tfs-2015, jasmine-reporters

I have the following project in my Visual Studio 2015 solution.  I want to execute jasmine tests as part of our TFS CI build.  I can run my tests successfully when I open the SpecRunner.html file although I'm failing to get them to run as part of the TFS build.  I've included a screen shot of my TFS build step definition.  The build is successful but the tests are not executed.

Please advise, any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

**Project and file locations**

[image: project and file locations]

**TFS build step**

[image]

Comment: Could you manually run the test on the build server? Please make sure your environment is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your environment on the build sever is set correct. You could manually run the test on the build server.

To use a [NuGet package for the Chutzpah test runner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah/) , then you can avoid having to manually unpack the VSIX and get it into source control to deploy it to the build host.

About the detail step and build definition you could take a look at this tutorial: [nUnit and Jasmine.JS unit tests in TFS/VSO vNext build](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04aug15/nunit-and-jasmine-js-unit-tests-in-tfs-vso-vnext-build/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've look at this page (the microsoft link) whilst trying to get it to work but failed.  I have downloaded the nuget Chutzpah package already

Comment: Did you also install the Chutzpah Test runner on your build server's Visual Studio. According to that link seems  package does not currently enable Visual Studio to find the Jasmine tests without the VSIX extension being installed. Moreover what's the detail error of your test task  in your build definition?

Comment: we have VS installed on the server but not Chutzpah.  I didn't realise we need that installed on the server as well..  Is that correct?

Comment: You must make sure the build agent(build server)  environment the same as your local environment.

Comment: okay I'll try and install Chutzpah, when you say install do you mean just the nuget package folder?

Comment: Just install Chutzpah(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.ChutzpahTestAdapterfortheTestExplorer) on the build server Visual Studio as a VSIX package to run the tests

Comment: Okay!  I'll try it and let you know!

Comment: I've installed it on the server, literally but going to the link you suggested and downloaded and installed.  What do I do in the TFS build steps to trigger it?

Comment: After install the VSIX, you could manually run the  jasmine tests for troubleshooting if it's an environment issue or build definition settings' issue. Then in your vNext build add **another** Visual Studio Test task, set the test assembly to match your JavaScript test naming convention **\*.tests.js and the path to the custom test adaptor to $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages such as above screenshot.

Comment: I see that in examples, how does the step know the search in the packages folder for Chutzpah?  Is it because the naming convention is *.js.  And secondly, if I want to run it manually on the tfs server how do I do that?  Thanks,

Comment: After setting the path  in the task TFS will **automatically searches subfolders, automatically scans any packages folder and installs and uses any NuGet packages containing test adapters without prompting.** As to run manually on the server, just mean using your build service account to load VS and run the Jasmine test run in the test runner(test explorer) as well as the MSTest and nUnit tests. I haven't tried with jasmine test, but should be the same with nUnit test.

Comment: Another related tutorial may be helpful : [TFS Build vNext : Running your JavaScript unit tests as part of your build process](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2016/11/tfs-build-vnext-running-your-javascript.html)

Comment: this is for C# tests, any examples that work for running Jasmine tests please?